# Convert datetime string with timezone value to Indian Standard Time (IST)

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a string which represents datetime with timezone, I am trying to convert it to Indian Standard Time (IST) by parsing the string.

Date string is,

```
"2018-12-24T02:35:16-08:00"
```

how can I know what's the actual time as per IST ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
utc_tz= tz.gettz('UTC')
india_tz= tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')
date_string="2018-12-24T02:35:16-08:00"
#utc = datetime.strptime(date_string[:date_string.rindex('-')].replace('T',' '), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# or
utc = datetime.strptime(date_string[:date_string.rindex('-')], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=utc_tz)
india_time_with_offset = utc.astimezone(india_tz)
india_time_without_offset = india_time_with_offset.replace(tzinfo=None)
print(india_time_with_offset)
print(india_time_without_offset)
```

Output

```
2018-12-24 08:05:16+05:30
2018-12-24 08:05:16
```